# React/Javascript Comparison Operator Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Somehow I couldn't get my comparison operators working. I have the following piece of code:

```
function handleNotifClickRemind(key) {
  localStorage.setItem('no_remind_change_pwd', true);
  notification.close(key);
}

// ...

<Button outline size="small" onClick={() => handleNotifClickRemind(key)}>
  Dont remind me
</Button>

// ...

console.log(localStorage.getItem('no_remind_change_pwd'));
function another_func(data) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('no_remind_change_pwd') != true) {
    openNotification('topRight');
  }
}
```

When I clicked the "Don't remind me" button, `handleNotifClickRemind` was triggered because the log output on the third section prints `true`. However, `openNotification` was still being triggered. Can anyone please help?

P.S. I didn't initialize the value, I just let `no_remind_change_pwd` be null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: getItem() returns a string or null. comparing to true doesn't make sense

Comment: Is `openNotification()` getting called before or after handleNotifClickRemind gets called?

Comment: I set the item to `true` on the first function, no?

Comment: `openNotification()` is called *before* `handleNCR`, but if I initialize the value to be *boolean* `false`, it wouldn't work

Comment: How is that `getItem()` returns a string though, I thought I assigned the storage either **true** or **false**? No quotation marks

Comment: Your explanation of what is happening doesn't match the code you've provided. From what's provided, it lioks like the log statement will happen whenever the page loads - it's not inside of `handleNotifClickRemind`. Same with the `openNotification` - the `if` statement surrounding it seems to run on page load.

Comment: @j1mbl3s my apologies, I forget to mention that the if statement is wrapped in a function. The function will be called the earliest among the three code sections above, but not on page load.

Comment: By the way, you are using non-strict (in)equality, `!=`. Since you are comparing `localStorage.getItem(...) != true`, you are checking the truthiness of the value and not that the value is actually `true`. For that, use [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you've saved in localstorage are strings.
So you are comparing `"true"!=true` which is always `true`.

If you want to compare the value, you can use like the following.
`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('no_remind_change_pwd')) != true`

That means, the following is `true`

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("true") === true)
```

Comment: I overlooked the type of localstorage. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry but answers could only be accepted after five minutes the question is posted (I believe)

Comment: Since it is the [inequality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Inequality) and not the strict inequality operator, why doesn't it convert the types?

Comment: @Marvin If one of the operand is Boolean, "==" operator converts both operands to Number format. Number("true") is NaN and Number(true) is 1, so it is false

Answer (score 1):

1. It's always good practice to use triple comparison operator like `===` or `!==`.
2. `localStorage.getItem()` return data in String format so if you want to compare with some boolean then first convert it to boolean. By `Boolean(localStorage.getItem('no_remind_change_pwd'))`.

```js
function another_func(data) {
  if (Boolean(localStorage.getItem('no_remind_change_pwd')) !== true) {
    openNotification('topRight');
  }
}
```

Hope this should clear your understanding.